# angular-ng-autocomplete doesn't close dropdown when clicked outside

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am trying to use "angular-ng-autocomplete"  (https://github.com/gmerabishvili/angular-ng-autocomplete) plugin in my ionic 5 app (Angular 12) but for some reason when I clicked outside dropdown list box, it doesn't close that dropdown list. It works fine in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete) example though.

I have tried to do it manually as well but still doesn't work. Here's my manual code

HTML

```
<div class="ng-autocomplete">
  <ng-autocomplete #auto
    [data]="items"
    [searchKeyword]="keyword"
    placeholder="Name"
    (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
    debounceTime='300'
    (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
    (inputFocused)='onFocusChanged($event)'
    [initialValue]='defaultValue'
    [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
    [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
  </ng-autocomplete>

  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
    <a [innerHTML]="item.name"></a>
  </ng-template>
   
  <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
    <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
  </ng-template> 
</div>
```

component

```
@ViewChild('auto') auto;

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickOut(event) {
      if (!event.target.attributes['autocomplete'] || event.target.attributes['autocomplete'].name !== 'autocomplete') 
      {
        this.auto.close();
      }
   }
```

Have tried to debug it but couldn't see what's wrong. Here's a video of it
https://streamable.com/b3aowi

Any suggestion would be much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-autocomplete #auto
  [data]="items"
  [searchKeyword]="keyword"
  placeholder="Name"
  (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
  debounceTime='300'
  (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
  (inputFocused)='onFocusChanged($event)'
  [initialValue]='defaultValue'
  [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
  [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate"
  (click)="$event.preventDefault()"
  >

</ng-autocomplete>
```

I tried this event binding whith preventDefault()  **(click)="$event.preventDefault()"**

It working fine for me.
Hope that this answer will help